# How to export draft and deleted emails to email account of Exchange?

Tags: c#, .net, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Can anybody suggest me link or way to synchronize(export) local emails of database with exchange mail account? I am using ews to download(import) emails of exchange mail account.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just exporting a mailbox, I suggest the New-MailboxExportRequest command via powershell.  That way you can script it to run on a schedule or just run at the drop of a hat.

Per: [New-MailboxExportRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607299(v=exchg.160).aspx)

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox samaccountname -FilePath "\\server\share\mbxnameorwhatever.pst"
```

The caveat is the "Exchange Trusted Subsystem" acct in AD needs Read/Write access to the share you're using and the acct that's running the command needs the ["Mailbox Import Export"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633452(v=exchg.141).aspx) role or have it available in a role group.

If you read through the New-MailboxExportRequest examples, you'll see you can add some pretty neat features, AND by default it will include the mailbox dumpster (really deleted items).  Hope this helps, if not, lemme know.

-Chase